# Devise Registration Ruby on Rails - Migration Error: Duplicate column name

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, user-registration

I'm encountering an issue while running a Rails migration that adds Devise to my Users table. The error message points to a duplicate column name, specifically "email." The migration file causing the problem is located at /Users/jaydenthelwell/pye-candles/pye-candles/db/migrate/20231115201715_add_devise_to_users.rb.

Here is the error:

`➜  pye-candles git:(master) ✗ rails db:migrate
== 20231115201715 AddDeviseToUsers: migrating =================================
-- change_table(:users)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: email
/Users/jaydenthelwell/pye-candles/pye-candles/db/migrate/20231115201715_add_devise_to_users.rb:7:in `block in up' /Users/jaydenthelwell/pye-candles/pye-candles/db/migrate/20231115201715_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in` up'

Caused by:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: email
/Users/jaydenthelwell/pye-candles/pye-candles/db/migrate/20231115201715_add_devise_to_users.rb:7:in `block in up' /Users/jaydenthelwell/pye-candles/pye-candles/db/migrate/20231115201715_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in` up'

Caused by:
SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: email
/Users/jaydenthelwell/pye-candles/pye-candles/db/migrate/20231115201715_add_devise_to_users.rb:7:in `block in up' /Users/jaydenthelwell/pye-candles/pye-candles/db/migrate/20231115201715_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in` up'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
➜  pye-candles git:(master) ✗ `

Here's the relevant the migration file:

`# frozen_string_literal: true

class AddDeviseToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
def self.up
change_table :users do |t|
## Database authenticatable
t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

```
  ## Recoverable
  t.string   :reset_password_token
  t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

  ## Rememberable
  t.datetime :remember_created_at

  ## Trackable
  # t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
  # t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
  # t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
  # t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
  # t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

  ## Confirmable
  # t.string   :confirmation_token
  # t.datetime :confirmed_at
  # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
  # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

  ## Lockable
  # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
  # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
  # t.datetime :locked_at


  # Uncomment below if timestamps were not included in your original model.
  # t.timestamps null: false
end

add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
# add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
# add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
```

end

def self.down
# By default, we don't want to make any assumption about how to roll back a migration when your
# model already existed. Please edit below which fields you would like to remove in this migration.
raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
end
end

`

I deleted the User migration file as I thought this was causing the issue, the users table also has "email" but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

After encountering the SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: email error, I revisited my create_users migration file. The issue arose because the columns Devise was attempting to add were already present in the original migration.

To resolve this, I recreated the users table in my migration as follows:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      # t.string :email, null: false, default: ""
      # t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""
      # t.string :reset_password_token
      # t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at
      # t.datetime :remember_created_at
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :second_name
      t.date :d_o_b
      t.string :phone_number
      t.string :address

      ## Other Devise fields if needed

      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email, unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # Add other indexes if needed
  end
end
```

But commented out

```
  # t.string :email, null: false, default: ""
  # t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""
  # t.string :reset_password_token
  # t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at
  # t.datetime :remember_created_at
```

I commented out the columns that Devise was attempting to add (email, encrypted_password, etc.), as these were already included in the original migration. After making this adjustment, the migration ran successfully without any issues.